# How to make webpack's uglifyjs plugin not break sass's source maps?

Tags: javascript, webpack, minify, source-maps, uglifyjs

Here's the setup:

`package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.26.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.24.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.13.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3"
  }
}
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './1.js',
    output: {
        path: 'dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.sass$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap!sass?sourceMap')},
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'template.ejs',
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
    ],
    devtool: 'source-map',
};
```

`template.ejs`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

`1.js`:

```
require('./1.sass');
```

`1.sass`:

```
body
    background: #ddd
div
    width: 100px
    height: 100px
    margin: auto
    background: #333
```

Then

```
$ rm -rf dist/* && ./node_modules/.bin/webpack
```

And open `http://example.com/dist` in Chrome. Then go to `Developer Tools` > `Elements tab`. Click on the `div`, and then on the link for `div { width: 100px; ... }` block. And you'll find yourself on line 2. But when you comment out the `new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()` line, you'll be at line 3, as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to mention is that `UglifyJsPlugin` [switches](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v1.13.3/lib/optimize/UglifyJsPlugin.js#L143) all loaders into minimizing mode. From [the docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#uglifyjsplugin):

> Minimize all JavaScript output of chunks. **Loaders are switched into minimizing mode.**

But thankfully it was changed in the [coming](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/283#issuecomment-179219468) [2.x version](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/283#issuecomment-186170757).

The other issue is that `libsass` generates [wrong source map](https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/2230), when `outputStyle` is `compressed`. And `outputStyle` is compressed, when you don't specify it [explicitly](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader/blob/v4.0.1/index.js#L216) and minification is turned on.

So, for now the workaround is to specify some `outputStyle` other than `compressed`:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './1.js',
    output: {
        path: 'dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.sass$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap!sass?sourceMap')},
        ]
    },
    sassLoader: {
        outputStyle: 'nested',
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'template.ejs',
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
    ],
    devtool: 'source-map',
};
```

**UPD** It seems there are also issues with most likely [`source-map`](https://github.com/mozilla/source-map/issues/252) package and [`css-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/379) package. So you might consider disabling minification, like in: `css?sourceMap&-minimize`.